# Response.redirect with asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp page that gets info, processes it and make and url

```
cadena="https://dominioexterno.com/actualizadatos.php?nombre="&nombre&"&identificador="&identificador&"&fecha="&fecha&"&tempe="&tempe&"&humedad="&humedad&"&lluvia="&lluvia&"&viento="&viento&"&funcion=actualiza"

response.redirect cadena
```

The page doesn't interact with the user, gets the info and sends it via response.redirect, but It didn't work.
When I paste the url in my navigator I get success but with the asp does...nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

your syntax looks fine, so to troubleshoot, I would try writing the url out to the screen, then copying and pasting that into a new browser window:

cadena="http

```
s://dominioexterno.com/actualizadatos.php?nombre="&nombre&"&identificador="&identificador&"&fecha="&fecha&"&tempe="&tempe&"&humedad="&humedad&"&lluvia="&lluvia&"&viento="&viento&"&funcion=actualiza"

Response.Write cadena
Response.End
```

if that works, then you have something wrong with the processing page. without more info, it'll be hard to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Josh, thanks for the answer.
It works fine that way.
 I've been reading and realice that with response.redirect can't acces a page of other domain, I get "object moved to here..." and blocked the redirection.

I don't know how I can get the data from my domain and pass those data to the  destination domain.

Comment: are you sending the data via POST or GET?